# Staying invisible on Google Plus

Tags: google-plus, privacy

I'm considering signing up for Google Plus to get all the alluring perks Google's offering, such as unlimited cloud space for photos and shorter videos. However, apart from sharing data with a few select family members, I want my data to be private and my profile to be as anonymous and hidden as possible for the rest of the world, to prevent people from finding me.

Is this achievable? What steps do I need to take in order to ensure maximum privacy, in effect merely using Google Plus as a private cloud storage service?

Comment: While I don't know any direct way to achieve this, you can set really strict privacy settings, making everything view-able to you only (read: hidden for public).

Comment: Your name and profile photo are public, but you can turn everything else off to just yourself or a select few people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your G+ personal rofile.

Then set up a Google+ Page.

Then give that Page its own password, and after that only log in as the Page, not as your personal profile.

The Page has practically the full G+ account functionality.   Google knows what human being it is tied to, but that's all.    The profile that's displayed is always the page's profile.

Comment: Good idea. In any case, set up your Profile and Settings so that the fields are private and most of the tabs are hidden. Then share your photos with a specific circle of friends.